# Silent parallel::makePSOCKcluster(..., outfile = "")

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I want to use `parallel::makePSOCKcluster(..., outfile = "")` to show output from worker processes, and I also want to hide the "starting worker" messages. Is this possible? Currently, I get:

```
> library(parallel)
> sink("/dev/null")
> cluster = makePSOCKcluster(4, outfile = "")
starting worker pid=6695 on localhost:11111 at 17:31:50.015
starting worker pid=6703 on localhost:11111 at 17:31:50.240
starting worker pid=6711 on localhost:11111 at 17:31:50.467
starting worker pid=6724 on localhost:11111 at 17:31:50.698
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to avoid those messages without modifying the `parallel` package. The `.slaveRSOCK` function always displays that message using `cat`, so if you specify `outfile=""`, you'll always see those messages.